# Express.js multiple methods

Tags: node.js, express

So in Express you can do:

```
app.get('/logo/:version/:name', function (req, res, next) {
    // Do something
}
```

and

```
app.all('/logo/:version/:name', function (req, res) {
    // Do something
}
```

Is there a way to just have two methods (ie. GET and HEAD)? Such as:

```
app.get.head('/logo/:version/:name', function (req, res, next) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I believe when a user does a HEAD request, it will invoke the GET request handler.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just pull out the anonymous function and give it a name:

```
function myRouteHandler(req, res, next) {
  // Do something
}

app.get('/logo/:version/:name', myRouteHandler);
app.head('/logo/:version/:name', myRouteHandler);
```

Or use a general middleware function and check the `req.method`:

```
app.use('/logo/:version/:name', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === 'GET' || req.method === 'HEAD') {
    // Do something
  } else
    next();
});
```

Comment: I like the second one.  Is app.all the same as app.use?

Comment: Not exactly. `app.all()` adds separate route handlers for every supported HTTP verb, whereas `app.use()` adds a single route handler that is executed for all requests (that match the optional route pattern).

Comment: Note that because express automatically implements a `HEAD` handler for you when you specify a `GET` handler, the `app.head()` will never run. You need to call `app.head()` before `app.get()` so that the `HEAD` request will be routed to your handler.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`.route()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.route) method.

```
function logo(req, res, next) {
    // Do something
}

app.route('/logo/:version/:name').get(logo).head(logo);
```

Answer (score 2):

another version:

```
['get','head'].forEach(function(method){
  app[method]('/logo/:version/:name', function (req, res, next) {
    // Do something
  });
});
```

Comment: If your `HEAD` and `GET` implementation are really the same, there’s no point in manually calling `app.head()` because express will automatically handle `HEAD` as long as you specify `app.get()`. So this version could be simplified to `app.get()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the array spread operator if your route pattern is the same for multiple methods.

e.g.

```
const route = [
    '/logo/:version/:name', 
    function handleRequest(req, res) {
        // handle request
    }
];

app.get(...route);
app.post(...route);
```