# How do I make a get-request <support> head-request in express?

Tags: node.js, express, request, header

I'm working on an exercise and it asks me to "*make all get-requests also support head-requests*".

I'm finding tons of tutorials on how to make ***get***-requests like:

```
app.get(/*someRounte*/, (req, res) => { // code });
```

I do know how to formulate a head-request: `app.head(...)`, but I haven't found a single source that says how I can make an endpoint support ***head***-requests.

Is there some kind of ***best practice*** on how to make an endpoint also support ***head***-requests?

Comment: What about `app.head` ?

Comment: Thank you @Rashomon. Yes sure, but I dont know how to use them. 

So lets say I have 5 routes and I want all 5 routes to also support head-requests..., so I create separate head-requests for all 5 get-requests?

Comment: I see. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025486/express-js-multiple-methods