# GET vs HEAD methods in Express. EXAMPLE

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to implement HEAD method in Node.js with Express server-side for a given GET method?

Can someone provide an example of usage of HEAD mehod vs GET method?

I mean code like:

Index.js

```
app.get ("/root", function (req, res) {

//some code
}) 

app.head ("/root", function (req, res) {

//some code
})
```

Comment: You're using Express?

Comment: Yes, I am using Express

Comment: ...`app.head(...)`?

Comment: See [Express.js multiple methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27025486/express-js-multiple-methods) for more information. In short: replace **app.get** with **app.head**.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but I need an example to clearify the difference GET vs HEAD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Http Head request is only used to request HTTP headers from the server and server must not return a body in it.

```
 app.head("/root",(req,res)=>{
       res.set('x-user', 'abcd')
    })
```

Http get request is only used to get some request some body and additional headers(if needed)

```
app.get("/root",(req,res)=>{
           res.json({email:'test'})
        })
```

Please note: Both the type of request should not change the state in the system. For changing the state use POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE methods

Comment: Ok, thanks, could you provide an example like this for POST vs PUT

Comment: Note: the `app.get()` function is automatically called for the HTTP `HEAD` method in addition to the `GET` method if `app.head()` was not called for the path before `app.get()`.